# dir inside function

Tags: python, scope

Python has a nice feature that gives the contents of an object, like all of it's methods and existing variables, called `dir()`. However when dir is called in a function it only looks at the scope of the function. So then calling `dir()` in a function has a different value than calling it outside of one. For example:

```
dir()
> ['__builtins__', '__doc__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__spec__']
def d():
  return dir()
d()
> []
```

Is there a way I can change the scope of the dir in d?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`dir()` *without an argument* defaults to the current scope (the keys of `locals()`, but sorted). If you wanted a different scope, you'd have to pass in an object. From the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#dir):

> Without arguments, return the list of names in the current local scope. With an argument, attempt to return a list of valid attributes for that object.

For the global scope, use `sorted(globals())`; it's the exact same result as calling `dir()` at the module level.